# How to Post to a Page in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I've got an App that posts pictures or videos to a FB Timeline and works fine. I now need to post to the 'Pages' within a FB account and am struggling - I'm sure it's just a syntax problem.

I've changed the permissions and included Manage_Pages and Publish_Pages;

I have done the command;

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/accounts', 'GET');
```

and retrieved the Tokens and list of pages in an array...all so far so good.

The code I'm trying to get to work is;

```
$ret_obj  = $facebook->post(
'/'.$pg1Id.'/feed',
array(
    "message" => "Message",
    "link" => "http://www.example.com",
    "picture" => "http://www.example.net/images/example.png",
    "name" => "Title",
    "caption" => "www.example.com",
    "description" => "Description example"
),
$pg1Token
```

);

where $pg1Id is the Id and $pg1Token is the Token for the page.
...not getting an error but it just fails !!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the request returning?

Comment: Just seems to be hanging and not returning anything.....

Comment: It will return something

Comment: Ok managed to get some more debugging in there and the results is "Call to undefined method Facebook::Post() .....

Any idea what that should be?